# Is it possible to adjust the CochranArmitageTest() function i R for additional variables?

Tags: r

I've tried to search for the answer to this question but have not found any.

Does the CochranArmitageTest() function in R support adjustments for additional variables, apart from the two-level dependent and k-leveled independent variable? How in that case should the x (frequency table or matrix) be presented for the function?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular test is specifically only written to assess a single ordinal or categorical variable and a binary outcome variable. It is not, as far as I know modifiable.

However, it is my understanding that the Bioconductor project, which curates a lot of pharmaceutical, biological and genetics packages in R, hosts a package developed about 5-years ago to work with multiple categorial or ordinal variables and  binary outcome.

It is in the `globaltest` package which you can install with the following directy from the Bioconductor repository.

`BiocManager::install("globaltest")`

[Here is the PDF explaining the whole package:](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/globaltest/inst/doc/GlobalTest.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @sconfluentus. I will look into the PDF and post here if I learn of any substantial option that could work as intended.